# AttributeError: type object 'Categories' has no attribute 'user_id__isnull' in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

When i use a queryset in django, i get this error:

**AttributeError: type object 'Categories' has no attribute 'user_id__isnull'**

The *Categories* model has a foreign key on the User model
named *user*.

When i use the queryset: `_Categories.objects.filter(Q(Categories.user_id__isnull==True ) | Q(user=user))_`, I essentially want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE user_id=NULL | user.id=user.id
```

*(user.id=user.id represents the currently logged in User)*

**forms.py:**

```
from .models import Task, Categories
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.db.models import Q

class TaskForm(ModelForm):

    task_title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    task_description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)        
    due_date = forms.DateTimeField()    
    is_completed = forms.BooleanField()
    #categories = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label="---None---")

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['task_title', 'task_description', 'due_date', 'is_completed', 'categories', 'parent']        

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get all the categories from the database for that specifc user
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['categories'].queryset = Categories.objects.filter(Q(Categories.user_id__isnull==True ) | Q(user=user))
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from users.models import CustomUser
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class Categories(models.Model):
    category_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null = True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s ' % (self.category_type)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task_list')


class Task(models.Model):
    task_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    task_description = models.TextField()
    date_added =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date  = models.DateTimeField()
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    categories = models.ForeignKey('Categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Task"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tasks"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s ID: %s' % (self.task_title, self.last_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task_detail')
```

**CustomUser model:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    nationality = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=60)
```

Comment: What's with the leading and trailing underscores? Neither of the two examples are syntactically sound. There's unclosed parentheses, `==` in SQL and underscores floating around

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the observation. I already corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queryset syntax is wrong. It should be:

```
Categories.objects.filter(Q(user_id__isnull=True) | Q(user_id=user.id))
```

Comment: Really appreciate your response. I tried this out. I guess it worked, but in the process, i got another error.   _TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <class 'users.models.CustomUser'>_  .. I guess its something related to the _Q(user=user)_

Comment: Yea, replace it with user_id=user.id, I'm gonna update the answer too

Comment: Thanks @engin_ipek. It worked, but I had another issue. When I ran, the output was,  `TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000002B6ADE878D0` . Is it a problem with my models or forms?